# Java Maven Jasperreport run from Eclipse Ok, from with java - jar JRRuntimeException: Chart theme "eye.candy.sixties" not found

Tags: java, maven, jasper-reports

I created a Java program which creates a report with JasperReports.
In one of my JasperReports I use the theme="eye.candy.sixties".

when I run the project from Eclipse in the gui, all is fine, see
[image]

However when I build the same project with Maven and run it from the commandline I get the error:

```
Maven: clean compile assembly:single
Command line: java -jar chartTheme-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

> Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Chart theme "eye.candy.sixties" not found.

**What am I missing, what should I change? Any help welcome!**

Source code can be found on Github: [ChartTheme](https://github.com/Forgev41/chartTheme.git)

I did include the chart theme dependency in Maven, see the "Maven dependencies list in Eclipse:

[image]
 and in the code below (pom.xml)

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.lightroomstatistics.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>chartTheme</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>chartTheme</name>
    <description>chartTheme</description>

    <url>www.lightroomstatistics.com</url>
    <organization>
        <name>LightroomStatistics</name>
        <url>www.lightroomstatistics.com</url>
    </organization>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.lightroomstatistics.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>lightroomstatistics-parent-pom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jasperreports.version>6.4.0</jasperreports.version>
        <jasperreportsfonts.version>4.0.0</jasperreportsfonts.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <!-- Needed for Jasperreports chart-themes -->
        <repository>
            <id>jr-ce-releases</id>
            <name>JasperReports CE Releases</name>
            <url>http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/jr-ce-releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>${jasperreports.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>${jasperreportsfonts.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jasperreports-chart-themes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-chart-themes</artifactId>
            <version>${jasperreports.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>reports</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>data</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-report-resources</id>
                        <!-- here the phase you need -->
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/reports</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>reports</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-data-resources</id>
                        <!-- here the phase you need -->
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/data</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>data</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>chartTheme.ChartThemesApp</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open your built joint-library `chartTheme-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`, you'll realize that the contents of file `jasperreports-char-themes-6.4.0.jar/jasperreports_extension.properties` are **misssing**, because they were overriden with the contents of some other `jasperreports_extension.properties` file also present in your dependencies.

In fact, if you search in the output console after running `mvn assembly`, you'll find these traces:

> [INFO] jasperreports_extension.properties already added, skipping

... which, by the way, is not the only one file skipped at assembly.

So, definitely it's not a good idea to assembly all of these dependencies together, because of the overlaps. At least, not in this way.

I think the first thing you should try is to parametrize the [assembly descriptor file](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) to exclude the undesired files priorizing the desired ones, which I presume will be the ones in `jasperreports-chart-themes.jar` (by the traces in the log you posted).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for looking into this problem. Little Santi explained to me what was the problem.
Also not liking to have a big JAR, I decided to put all the dependency jar in a separate lib directory / folder. This worked fine.

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>chartTheme.ChartThemesApp</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I think it is much better than having a big Jar. Congratulations!